# What is the reason for IO application not closing its execution?

Tags: scala, logging, concurrency, slf4j, scala-3

Why does this hang?

```scala
import cats.effect.IO
import cats.effect.unsafe.implicits.global
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory
import io.circe.config.parser
import org.typelevel.log4cats._
import org.typelevel.log4cats.slf4j._

object ItsElenApp extends App:

  private val logger: SelfAwareStructuredLogger[IO] = LoggerFactory[IO].getLogger

  val ops = for
    _ <- logger.info("aa")
    _ <- IO(println("bcc"))
    _ <- logger.error("bb")
  yield ()

  ops.unsafeRunSync()

  println("end")
```

It prints:

```
INFO 2022-06-19 11:56:25,303 ItsElenApp - aa
bcc
```

and keeps running. Is it the log4cats library, or am I using the App object in a wrong way. Or do I have to close an execution context?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The recommended way of running `cats.effect.IO`-based apps is using `cats.effect.IOApp` (or `cats.effect.ResourceApp`):

```
object MyApp extends IOApp:

  // notice it takes List[String] rather than Array[String]
  def run(args: List[String]): IO[ExitCode] = ...
```

this would run the application, handle setting up exit code, etc. [It closes the app when `run` reaches the end](https://github.com/typelevel/cats-effect/blob/245d13ce5c6a4171a984401d57fb9c5ded719b1b/core/js/src/main/scala/cats/effect/IOApp.scala#L238), which might be necessary if the default thread pool is non-daemon. If you don't want to use `IOApp` you might need to close JVM manually, also taking into consideration that exception might have been thrown on `.unsafeRunSync()`.

Extending `App` is on the other hand not recommended in general. Why? It uses special `Delayed` mechanism where the whole body of a class (its constructor) is lazy. This makes it harder to reason about the initialization, which is why this mechanism became deprecated/discouraged. If you are not using IOApp it is better to implement things like:

```
object MyProgram:

  // Java requires this signature
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = ...
```

which in your case could look like

```
object ItsElenApp:

  private val logger: SelfAwareStructuredLogger[IO] = LoggerFactory[IO].getLogger

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit =
    val ops = for
      _ <- logger.info("aa")
      _ <- IO(println("bcc"))
      _ <- logger.error("bb")
    yield ()

    // IOApp could spare you this
    try
      ops.unsafeRunSync()
    finally
      println("end")
      sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried the raw `def main` example, it runs well. Even if I'm not looking out for errors, without the try-finally and `sys.exit`, it runs okay. So weird what is happening with the the async threads. But I guess `App` is just totally wrong to use.

Comment: `App` is a nice for intro classes to not scare people away with `main` in Hello World, but it makes it harder to reason about how your code is initialized. I am not sure what exactly happens when you run your original code, I would have to compile it and look at the bytecode directly. With manually written `main` I find it relatively easy to tell what is initialized when which helps debugging cases like yours.

Answer (score 0):

Because log4cats' logging functions seem to be asynchronous. Meaning they might run on a different thread, not in sequence with the other operations.

That means the main thread might finish but the other threads keep being opened and never closing.

If I use `ops.unsafeRunTimed(2.seconds)` everything executes and closes. But the latter log lines come only at the end of the time. Looks like the logging is somehow lazy and only finishes if it is asked to. I'm not sure.

They write you shouldn't use `unsafeRunTimed` in production code.

Of course if you use `IOApp`, everything executes normally again.

But how would you write this in production code, cleanly, nicely without an `IOApp`? I think there should be a clean way of telling log4cats to finish the operations, return their async fibers results and close everything. All manually.

Comment: Coincidentally written at the same time as Mateusz's answer.